# Why does using git deployment instead of docker deployment give me different results when all of my files are the same?

Tags: git, docker, heroku

I am new in Heroku's world

I use to deploy my apps using the command:

```
heroku container:push web
```

And all works fine!

Now, I want to deploy pushing my code to Heroku's remote repository and the deployment fails with the message:

> =!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues: build.docker.web references a Dockerfile that does
> not exist

My Dockerfile and heroku.yml are in the same folder

[image]

this is my heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Is it possible to deploy a docker container using git (maintaining a possibility of deploying with `heroku container` command) in Heroku?

Should I run some additional commands to deploy images using git?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: At a glance, the `build` section of your `heroku.yml` looks fine. Is that file UTF-8 encoded? What line endings does it use? I suggest using Unix-style line endings.

Comment: Side note: the `WGFinder.sln` file makes me think you're using .NET or .NET Core. The `web` process you've defined in your `run` section is for Ruby applications. I'm not sure what it would be for .NET Core, but it probably isn't that.